# Task.RunSynchronously() doesn’t care about CancellationToken

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I want to execute a 3rd party function on the current thread (to avoid overhead) but want to be able to use a *CancellationToken* to interrupt the function at any time.

That's how I create and run the task:

```
var task = new Task(proc, cts.Token); // cts is my CancellationTokenSource
task.RunSynchronously();
```

After `cts.Cancel()` was called (on a separate thread) **the task doesn't stop**.

I found a static function in F# which would do the trick:

```
Async.RunSynchronously(computation, timeout, cancellationToken)
```

I'm convinced that there should be a simple C# solution, can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how cancellation tokens work.  They do not kill the worker threads- the worker function needs to periodically check the cancellation token and see if it should stop.  From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997289(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997289%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The objects that receive the notification can respond in whatever manner is appropriate.

See much more information, including examples, here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Short story- if you want to stop executing a thread that's running a third party function that doesn't honor cancellation tokens, you'll need to find another way.

Comment: Then I wonder, what is the cancellation token in the task constructor just for???

Comment: It lets you cancel scheduling the task before it first runs. But once the task starts running, it can only be cancelled by the task code itself and the token sent to the constructor is meaningless.